# Таблица-обертка для сопоставления суррогатного и составного ключа

Tags: sql, база-данных

При разработке программы необходимо использовать базу данных, применяемую уже много лет до меня.

Основной недостаток данной базы состоит в больших составных ключах.

**Рассмотрим пример**

В системе есть таблица со списком справочников.
Первичный ключ таблицы справочников состоит из 2ух столбцов (пример выдуманный, но показательный):

- Код организации
- Номер справочника

Есть таблица с перечнем единиц измерения, где первичный ключ состоит из трех столбцов:

- Код организации
- Номер справочника
- Код единиц измерения

Допустим есть таблица с перечнем параметров. Каждый параметр имеет единицы измерения. С тем подходом, который приведен выше,

- Код организации
- Номер справочника
- Код единиц измерения
- Значение параметра

Сейчас мне необходимо разрабатывать программу, которая будет использовать данную базу данных.
Я собираюсь создавать дополнительные таблицы, которые будут ссылаться на справочники. В моих таблицах будут использоваться суррогатные ключи для удобства работы.

То, как организована работа со справочниками меня не устраивает.
Соответственно возникла идея создания таблицы-обертки типа:

- Ключ справочника (простое число)
- Код организации
- Номер справочника

Тогда работа с параметрами ужимается до:

- Ключ справочника
- Код единиц измерения
- Значение параметра

Стоит ли применять такой подход при разработке программы? В таком случае я смогу избежать влияния структуры данных на программную модель.

Comment: Если задача обратной совместимости не стоит, то ИМХО стоит привести базу к нормальному виду с сурогатными ключами... и не только таблицу справочников, но и единиц измерения и, возможно, параметров. Само собой добавив UNIQ-индексы по старым ключам. Если  обратная совместимость требуется, то надо оценить, что будет сложнее продолжить работать как есть или перевести базу к адекватному виду, а для старого софта создать VIEW'хи приводящие БД к привычному им виду...

Comment: Дело в том, что база данных общая с другой программой, которой уже много лет. Интеграция с этой программой идет через базу данных. Поэтому я не могу (хоть и хотел бы) переделывать текущие таблицы базы данных. Однако я не хочу, чтобы структура базы данных "диктовала" свои условия программной модели. Поэтому у меня и возникла идея создания таблиц-оберток. Правда таких таблиц будет много. Однако в таком случае я смогу спокойно создавать нужную мне программную модель (работа с базой данных идет через репозиторий)

Comment: повторю свою основную мысли, если СУБД серьёзная (а не какой-нить мускуль или sqlite), то можно переделать текущие таблицы, а совместимый интерфейс для старого ПО добить создав представления, но настаивать на этой идее не буду т.к. подводных камней у этого способа много, трудозатрат тоже, а применимость довольно ограниченна... так что только в качестве возможной идеи...

Comment: Оцените перспективы судьбы старого ПО. Новое - заменяет, дополняет? Старое - продолжит существовать, будет переделываться, заменяться, выводиться из эксплуатации? Вот это и должно лечь в основу идеи. А вариантов масса - от представлений (причём в обе стороны) и до триггерной синхронизации...

Comment: Akina, новое и старое ПО будут существовать параллельно. Старое ПО продолжает развиваться и активно использовать базу данных, в том числе и часть данных, вводимых программой, которую разрабатываю я (интеграция через базу данных). Поэтому я не могу менять структуру старых таблиц и решил создавать такие таблицы-обертки. Моя программа генерирует Guid для нужных объектов. В соответствии сгенерированному ключу формируется ссылка (составной внешний ключ формата старой программы). Также заносятся данные в таблицу, на которую ссылается внешний ключ.

Comment: Моя программа ориентируется на Guid. В тех случаях, где у моей и старой программы общие данные, осуществляется их поиск по связке Guid-Внешний ключ старой таблицы - извлекаю данные по внешнему ключу. В остальных случаях просто использую новые таблицы, где данным соответствует не внешний составной ключ таблицы старой программы, а данные новой программы. Повторюсь, я не могу менять первичные ключи старых таблиц. И старая программа должна обращаться к общим данным по своим ключам. Поэтому решил генерировать для таких данных два ключа: Guid-ключ для моей программы, а также внешний ключ для старой.